# How to mutate with query params in SWR hook?

Tags: reactjs, swr

currently i am using SWR to data fetching, i trying to use **Mutation** feature of SWR to refetch the new data but this occurred a problem when i am calling mutate() by **key** was added new query params.

Here's my code not working:

```
import useSWR, { useSWRConfig } from 'swr'

function Profile () {
  const { mutate } = useSWRConfig()
  const { data } = useSWR('/api/post', fetcher)

  return (
    <div>

      <h1>Title post {data.title}.</h1>

      <button onClick={() => {            
        mutate('/api/post?author=1&pricing=1')
      }}>
        View more information of this post!
      </button>

    </div>
  )
}
```

I read docs from SWR and i know the key of the mutate should be the same to key in useSWR() but in my case need more query params to get the corresponding data

How can i solve this problem?
Helps me please!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend using `mutate` in this scenario because the `key` (the URL) you want to use in the mutation is different from the original one. When `mutate` is called it'll update the cache for `'/api/post'` which will then contain data from `'/api/post?author=1&pricing=1'` in it.

As an alternative, I'd suggest you make the `key` an array in the `useSWR` call so that multiple arguments can be passed to the `fetcher`.

```js
const [queryParams, setQueryParams] = useState('')
const { data } = useSWR(['/api/post', queryParams], fetcher)
```

Then, in your button `onClick` handler, you can update the `queryParams` state value to trigger a re-render and initiate a new request with the query parameters.

```js
<button onClick={() => {            
    setQueryParams('?author=1&pricing=1')
}}>
    View more information of this post!
</button>
```

You also need to modify the `fetcher` function slightly to expect multiple arguments, and also append the query params you pass to the URL.

```js
const fetcher = (url, queryParams = '') => {
    // Example fetch to demonstrate the logic
    return fetch(`${url}${queryParams}`)
}
```

With this change you now have different keys (and cached data) for each URL you make a request for.